# vuejs get selected value in custom dropdown component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a custom select component and trying to set the data prop `selectedOffer` to the value selected in the select, however `$event` is passing an empty value.

How can I set selectedOffer to the value of the dropdown?

**offersList.vue**

```
 <dropdown
              :options="userOffers"
              :value="selectedOffer"
              :item-title-key="'title'"
              :item-value-key="'id'"
              :item-id-key="'id'"
              @optionSelected="setSelectedOffer($event)" />
```

**offersList.js**

```
 data() {
    return {
      userOffers: [{title: 'aus ITA'},{title: 'aus DE'}],
      selectedOffer: '',
    };
  },
 methods: {
    setSelectedOffer(value) {
      this.selectedOffer = value;
      console.log(this.selectedOffer);
    },
  },
```

**dropdown.vue**

```
<select
          :id="id"
          :name="name"
          @change="$emit('optionSelected', $event.target.value)">
        <slot/>
        <option
            v-for="item in options"
            :title="item[itemTitleKey]"
            :value="item[itemValueKey]"
            :key="item[itemIdKey]">
          {{ item[itemTitleKey] }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

Comment: FYI, use kebab-cased event names. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: yes I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Using v-model on Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) for a guide on custom form components.

The basic idea is that your component implements the `v-model` pattern by accepting a `value` prop and emitting an `input` event.

```js
Vue.component("dropdown", {
  template: `
    <select @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
      <slot>
        <option value="" :disabled="!!value">Select...</option>
      </slot>
      <option
        v-for="item in options"
        :title="item[itemTitleKey]"
        :value="item[itemValueKey]"
        :key="item[itemIdKey]"
        :selected="value == item[itemValueKey]"
      >
       {{ item[itemTitleKey] }}
      </option>
    </select>`,
  props: {
    value: [String, Number],
    options: Array,
    itemTitleKey: {
      type: String,
      default: "title"
    },
    itemValueKey: {
      type: String,
      default: "id"
    },
    itemIdKey: {
      type: String,
      default: "id"
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    userOffers: [{id: 1, title: 'aus ITA'},{id: 2, title: 'aus DE'}],
    selectedOffer: null,
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <dropdown
    :options="userOffers"
    v-model="selectedOffer"
    item-title-key="title"
    item-value-key="id"
    item-id-key="id"
  ></dropdown>
  
  <pre>selectedOffer = {{ selectedOffer }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: and how would I get it to display the title instead of id as the value?